# Issues with ARMv7-A bare metal call stack

Tags: c, assembly, arm, bare-metal

I'm trying to get a small ARM kernel up and running on QEMU (Versatile     Express for Cortex-A15). Currently it simply sets `sp` to the top of a small stack and sends a single character to UART0.

---

_start.arm:

```
.set stack_size, 0x10000
.comm stack, stack_size

.global _start
_start:
    ldr sp, =stack+stack_size
    bl start
1:
    b 1b
.size _start, . - _start
```

start.c:

```
/* UART_0 is a struct overlaid on 0x1c090000 */

void printChar(char c)
{
    while (UART_0->flags & TRANSMIT_FULL);
    UART_0->data = c;
}

void start()
{
    while (UART_0->flags & TRANSMIT_FULL);
    UART_0->data = 'A';

    printChar('a');
}
```

---

From GDB, I know that execution progresses through `_start` into `start` and successfully sends `'A'` to UART_0. `printChar` gets called and completes, but doesn't seem to print anything to the serial port . When running without GDB, the kernel repeatedly prints `'A'`, though I'm not sure if this is the processor resetting or jumping incorrectly.

From `objdump`:

```
Disassembly of section .stub:
00010000 <_start>:
   10000:   e59fd004    ldr sp, [pc, #4]    ; 1000c <__STACK_SIZE+0xc>
   10004:   eb000016    bl  10064 <start>
   10008:   eafffffe    b   10008 <_start+0x8>
   1000c:   000200d0    .word   0x000200d0

Disassembly of section .text:
00010010 <printChar>:
   10010:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
   10014:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
   10018:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12
   1001c:   e1a03000    mov r3, r0
   10020:   e54b3005    strb    r3, [fp, #-5]
   10024:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   10028:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
   1002c:   e3413c09    movt    r3, #7177   ; 0x1c09
   10030:   e1d331ba    ldrh    r3, [r3, #26]
   10034:   e6ff3073    uxth    r3, r3
   10038:   e2033020    and r3, r3, #32
   1003c:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
   10040:   1afffff8    bne 10028 <printChar+0x18>
   10044:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
   10048:   e3413c09    movt    r3, #7177   ; 0x1c09
   1004c:   e55b2005    ldrb    r2, [fp, #-5]
   10050:   e6ff2072    uxth    r2, r2
   10054:   e1c320b2    strh    r2, [r3, #2]
   10058:   e24bd000    sub sp, fp, #0
   1005c:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
   10060:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00010064 <start>:
   10064:   e52db008    str fp, [sp, #-8]!
   10068:   e58de004    str lr, [sp, #4]
   1006c:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
   10070:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   10074:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
   10078:   e3413c09    movt    r3, #7177   ; 0x1c09
   1007c:   e1d331ba    ldrh    r3, [r3, #26]
   10080:   e6ff3073    uxth    r3, r3
   10084:   e2033020    and r3, r3, #32
   10088:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
   1008c:   1afffff8    bne 10074 <start+0x10>
   10090:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
   10094:   e3413c09    movt    r3, #7177   ; 0x1c09
   10098:   e5d32002    ldrb    r2, [r3, #2]
   1009c:   e3a02000    mov r2, #0
   100a0:   e3822041    orr r2, r2, #65 ; 0x41
   100a4:   e5c32002    strb    r2, [r3, #2]
   100a8:   e5d32003    ldrb    r2, [r3, #3]
   100ac:   e3a02000    mov r2, #0
   100b0:   e5c32003    strb    r2, [r3, #3]
   100b4:   e3a00061    mov r0, #97 ; 0x61
   100b8:   ebffffd4    bl  10010 <printChar>
   100bc:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
   100c0:   e59db000    ldr fp, [sp]
   100c4:   e28dd004    add sp, sp, #4
   100c8:   e49df004    pop {pc}        ; (ldr pc, [sp], #4)

000100cc <UART_0>:
   100cc:   1c090000                                ....
```

Comment: Where does the PINSEL/ UART/whatever get set up?  Is the UART powered up?

Comment: The peripherals are handled by QEMU (launched with `-kernel`), which loads the binary into memory at `0x10000`. The UART is definitely powered up, since I can write to it from both `_start` and `start()`; the issue is writing to it during a function call.

Comment: install an exception vector before calling start. This will tell you what exactly went wrong. If you get back with the cause of exception, folks would be able to dig in the right direction.

Comment: @Notlikethat Color me impressed, that's it! The stack was in Flash and I just had to move it into PSRAM.

Comment: Good stuff. BTW, have no shame in the dupe - bare-metal is _all about_ unexpected ways things can go wrong with non-obvious symptoms ;)

Answer (score 0):

I may have missed something, but I am not seeing where you have enabled interrupts, or poll to see if you can send the next character.  If you have enabled the interrupts and set up the UART hardware correctly, your driver my have a bug.  If you have not setup the UART hardware correctly, it may not be generating interrupts, or it may not be doing the FIFO correctly, or any number of other problems.

Comment: The thing is, I know the UART is working because the first character is sent and printed. It's only when using a function that the printing doesn't work.

Comment: I see from above that it was a stack thing - I'm glad you found the answer.  I did miss the polling, so I'm sorry about that.